# Groupby reduction in OpenCL?

Tags: parallel-processing, mapreduce, opencl, reduce

I want to implement a groupby reduction in OpenCL. For example, the input

```
a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 c3 c4
```

would produce

```
a6 b3 c7
```

The C pseudocode looks like this:

```
int data[n][2], result[n][2], result_count = -1, 
    added = 0, group = data[0][0];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
  if (group == data[i][0]) {
    added += data[i][1];
  } else {
    result[++result_count][0] = group;
    result[result_count][1] = added;
    group = data[i][0];
    added = 0;
  }
} 
return result, result_count;
```

The only standard algorithm I know which goes in this direction is parallel reduction; however, it reduces to one number and not to a buffer of added values by group. I am not sure if parallel reduction could work with a dynamic result buffer (e.g. in local memory) and still be efficient in terms of performance.

Comment: Have you considered trying something similar to Thrust's [zip iterators](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/wiki/QuickStartGuide#zip_iterator)? Thrust doesn't have OpenCL support but you may be able to derive inspiration from their CUDA code. Zip iterators allow for multiple output sequences similar to what you're interested in.

Comment: IIUC zip iterators offer merely a way to perform e.g. a reduction with n-tuple data sets but reduce still would produce only one n-tuple and not an array/list of n-tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution by Hashing

Phase 1)  A hashing scheme  can be used to hash the group value to a location, then an atomic add can sum the contents of the second value.

Phase 2) A prefix sum  scan algorithm pass over the hash table to compact it.

Phase 3)  Optionally sort the results

A solution by Sorting

Phase 1) Sort the data on the group value

Phase 2) Use a reduction to sum each group

Phase 3) A prefix sum scan  to compact the sums